# xDebug plugins in VS code could NOT be triggered via Web pages with error message "connection read ECONNRESET"

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using VScode (1.43.1) + xDebug(2.9.3) on Windows 10 to debug my PHP (7.4.3 VC15 TS x64) scripts. I've followed Xdebug instructions to update php.ini and VScode launch.json, and am able to debug scripts under cli mode.

However i failed to trigger breakpoint via Web page in 99% time, when i start a php scripts from webpage, in VScode DEBUG console, i receive 'connection x: read ECONNRESET' message and breakpoint is not triggered. occasionally however, breakpoint could be reached.

Here it is my configured launch.json file:

```
enter code here
```

```
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "xDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "CLI",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
        ]
    }


    [xdebug]
    zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.3-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 
    xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

I appreciate you shed some lights on this.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: I have the same problem here! Have you found a solution?